# Pinch zoom working for Android and Windows Phone but not for iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, zooming, viewport, pinch

We created a PHP web page that is loading, zooming in and out just fine on Android and Windows Phone default browsers. But when we tested the page in iPhone, the pinch zoom does not work for some reason.

The page does a "require_once" for the menu. Both the page and the menu have the following viewport meta tag:

meta name="viewport" content="width=945, initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=10.0, minimum-scale=0.25,user-scalable=yes;"

Wonder if anything needs to change in the viewport itself or there is something else I should look into.

Thank you.